# err_too_many_redirects nginx when using rewrite rule for removing slash from url

Tags: nginx, configuration

My problem is connected with the next situation: when I`m trying to add a rule to remove slash from the url, I see the next error code "err_too_many_redirects"(if I try to check that such kind of links like site.com/images/ or other directory link return 403 code )

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;#remove slash
}
```

Could anyone help me to find soultion for this problem?

Site is working on nginx + php-fpm.

Comment: You can't use `$uri/` in a slash-less design, because it's primary purpose is to add the slash back on.

Comment: Ok, but can you give me any idea to find the solution of this problem? Because, I really needed in  this line(`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string`), it allows "pretty" URLs for my site.
What should I do? Check if the file exists in the separated rule?

Comment: What URIs do you want to support? Slash-less directories containing an index.php or an index.html. And files with a normal extension like `.php`, `.css` and `.js` etc.?

Comment: Such URIs like `/page/page-url`.

I have only one index.php file on the public directory(I'm using Laravel framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a situation where the following URL causes a 403 error, because the directory `images` actually exists:

```
example.com/images/
```

The problem is caused by the `$uri/` element on the `try_files` directive attempting to locate the index for the directory.

By removing that element (and the `rewrite` directive), the requested URI should be passed to `/index.php` for processing as a *pretty URL*. Try:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

If you need to apply an `index` to some directories within your hierarchy, you can specify the rule explicitly (rather than using `$uri/` and the `index` directive), by using (for example):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Well, good idea, thank you. I didn't remove remove rewrite rule, so I have such kind of this know:
`location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }`

So if I try to enter on the /images/ directory, the server redirects me to the 404 page.

A few times ago, I used another decision, I wrote something like this
`location ~ ^/images/(.*)/$ {                                                                        return 403;
    }` (for any real directory in my public folder). But it isn't very beautiful, your decision is better.